# Chapter header wanted in a separate page

Tags: titles, chapters

As the title indicates I want the chapters' titles to appear in the middle of a separate page.

Comment: Do you have a MWE (minimal working example)? Consider looking at the `titlesec` package under `titleformat` and probably edit the chapter style of your document class and add a `\newpage` to the chapter style so that it creates a new page.

Comment: added "wanted" to title to distinguish from questions that report a chapter title appearing unwanted on a separate page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is crudely stolen from [azeinta's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139625/15874) with the request in the comment incorporated.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\vspace*{\fill}
 \titlerule[1pt]%
 \vspace{1pt}%
 \titlerule
 \vspace{1pc}%
 \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule\Huge}
[\vspace*{\fill}\newpage]

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}
\lipsum{1-5}

\end{document}
```

If you don't want the chapter title page to be counter as a page in your document, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]% command + shape
{%
 \normalfont
 \Large
 \filcenter
 \sffamily
} % format
{%
 \vspace*{\fill}
 \titlerule[1pt]%
 \vspace{1pt}%
 \titlerule
 \vspace{1pc}%
 \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter%
}% label
{
 1pc
}% separation
{
 \titlerule
 \Huge
} % before
[%
 \vspace*{\fill}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \clearpage
 \addtocounter{page}{-1}
]% after

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test~A}
\lipsum{1-5}

\chapter{Test~B}
\lipsum{1-5}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\titlerule[1pt]%
\vspace{1pt}%
\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\Huge}
[\newpage] % creates the new page

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\lipsum{1-5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is how the titleformat is configured:

```
\titleformat{command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before}[after]
```

Check out the `titlesec` package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I want the title to be exactly in the center of the page (vertically). Any help would be much appreciated