# how to make only the chapter-titles to be in the middle of a new page

Tags: formatting, titlesec, titletoc

I am using Thesis.cls to write my thesis (From [Easy Thesis](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/easy-thesis) tempalate).

I wish to have the chapter title in a separate page and at the middle of the page.

For that I browse the internet and I got some suggestions.

(a) I got the below from [here1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182894/title-chapter-in-middle-of-page-latex)

```
   \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{250pt}{40pt}
```

(b) I got the below from  [here2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139621/chapter-header-wanted-in-a-separate-page)

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]% command + shape
{%
 \normalfont
 \Large
 \filcenter
 \sffamily
} % format
{%
 \vspace*{\fill}
 \titlerule[1pt]%
 \vspace{1pt}%
 \titlerule
 \vspace{1pc}%
 \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter%
}% label
{
 1pc
}% separation
{
 \titlerule
 \Huge
} % before
[%
 \vspace*{\fill}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \clearpage
 \addtocounter{page}{-1}
]% after
```

I tried both of the above suggestions but applying them into my template, each one gives me similar kind of distortion to the existing format of my document.

What happen is the sections like **Title of Contents**, **List of Figure**, **List of Table**, and **Appendix** all are positioned at the middle of their respective pages. I don't want this kind of format.

I want only the Chapter title (like Chapter1, Chapter2, etc...) to be in a new page and positioned at the middle of the page.

What should I do for getting the format I want? Appreciate any help in advance.

I want something like this

[image: Sample picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines just before the `\begin{document}`

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\vspace*{\fill}
 \titlerule[1pt]%
 \vspace{1pt}%
 \titlerule
 \vspace{1pc}%
 \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule\Huge}
[\vspace*{\fill}\newpage]

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[1pt]\Huge}
[\titlerule]

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
```

[image]

[image]

For the queries raised in comments, you can fiddle with the font attribute like this:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{showframe}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
 \chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
{0.5pc}
{\Huge}
[\vspace*{\stretch{1}}\clearpage]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{}
{0pt}
{\Huge}
[]
```

Comment: Excellent solution. But the fonts and format of the chapter title wanted like how I posted in the question. (Sorry I re-edited the post to add the picture for you).  Thank you.

Comment: @Vijay: please see the edit.