# changing format of chapter name

Tags: chapters

I am writing my master's thesis with documentclass{book} and I wanna change my chapter style.

As with the simple " \chapter{} " command, I get something like

[image]

But I want the chapter number and chapter name to be in the center of the page and the remaining subsection stuff should start on the next page.

Thanks

Comment: There are many examples here of modified chapter headings.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/fancy-chapter-headings?r=SearchResults&s=2|88.2985  and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539329/centering-chapter-number-and-title?r=SearchResults&s=2|59.7165 for example.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139621/134144 could also be helpful.

Comment: It is easily done with the `titlesec` package. See in particuler §3, *Advanced Interface`*, pp.3–11.